# Xcode 9 Archive process fails

Tags: xcode9, swift4

I'm working on a project which was initially started in Xcode 8.3 and Swift 3.2, after release of Xcode 9(stable version) I converted my project from Swift 3.2 to Swift 4.0 using inbuilt option in Xcode 9. it also converted pods like Alamofire, SwiftyJson and more. I've also updated all pods using        `pod update` command.
 
everything is running fine in simulator as well as on iPhone but when I try to archive project the archive process fails with error as below.[Error Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4EJ2.png)
[Error Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1SKp.png)

I've tried all possible solutions like changing **Swift Language Version**, **Optimization Level** for both Target & Pods **Build Settings** but it didn't works. 
I've also tried in my pod file.

```
swift_32 = ['Alamofire', 'AlamofireImage', 'AssistantKit'] # if these pods are in Swift 3.2
swift4 = ['SwiftyJSON'] # if these pods are in Swift 4

post_install do |installer|

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        swift_version = nil

        if swift_32.include?(target.name)
            swift_version = '3.2'
        end

        if swift4.include?(target.name)
            swift_version = '4.0'
        end

        if swift_version
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = swift_version
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Building and running project works but only archive process fails with above mention error.

Comment: Please add the error messages you are getting as text rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar type of issue. I was able to run my Xcode project with pods installed i.e `Alamofire, SwiftyJson` etc. but every time I try to archive the process fails by showing above error. The cause of problem is with cocoapods.
 
Removing cocoapods completely and reinstalling it again solved my issue.

To remove cocoapods completely from MacOS:
 1. Type `gem list --local | grep cocoapods` in the terminal. You’ll see something like this in terminal:

> cocoapods (1.3.1)
>  cocoapods-core (1.3.1)
>  cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.1)
>   cocoapods-downloader (1.1.3)
>  cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
>   cocoapods-search (1.0.0)
>  cocoapods-stats (1.0.0)
>  cocoapods-trunk
>   (1.3.0)
>  cocoapods-try (1.1.0)

2. Now you need to remove each gem with below command one by one.

> sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
>  sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-deintegrate
>   sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader

3. Also delete ~/.cocoapods to remove the cache of podspecs. this will remove old master repo.

> rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/

4. Remove pods from your Xcode project & delete Podfile. I also deleted my .xcworkspace.

> pod deintegrate
>  rm Podfile

5. Now after all of this reinstall cocoapods using:

> sudo gem install cocoapods
>  pod setup --verbose

Add required pods to your project and try to archive.
Hope this will help.